# How is a password check structured in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

The database-dependent portion of my login function isn't working. Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong? Is it an installation error, am I not connecting to the server properly, or is it a syntax problem?
I haven't written the php form yet; I wanted to have code for each of the possible login errors first.

The node.js (without database-specific information)

```
    $ export MYSQL_CONFIG=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
    $ npm install db-mysql
    var mysql = require('db-mysql');
    new mysql.Database({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        user: 'user',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'test'
    }).connect(function(error) {
        if (error) {
            document.getElementById('fail').innerHTML='CONNECTION error: ' + error
        }
        this.query('SELECT `password` FROM `login` WHERE `email` LIKE \'' + document.getElementById('email').value + '\'').
            execute(function(error, rows, cols) {
                    if (error) {
                            document.getElementById('fail').innerHTML='ERROR: ' + error
                            return;
                    }
                    else if (rows.length !== 0) {
                        document.getElementById('fail').innerHTML="This email is already registered to an account"
                    }
                    else if (rows ==      document.getElementById('password').value) {
                        document.getElementById('fail').innerHTML="The     password you have entered is incorrect"
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        window.location = "profile.html";
                    }
            });
    });
```

The simple version of the HTML

```
 <head></head>
 <body><br><center>
 <big id="fail"></big><br>
 <form action="" method="post">
     <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="e"></input>
     <br>
     <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="p">    </input>
     <br><br>
     <input type="button" value=" Sign In  " onclick="login()"></input>
     <input type="button" value=" Register " onclick="register()"></input>
</form>
</center>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Am I reading this wrong, or are you trying to access `document` (which is a browser variable) in your node.js (which is the server)? Do you have some form of DOM parsing going on in your server?